# Installing segmented profile package unto an ISD-P on eUICC through SCP03t

Tags: smartcard, javacard, emv, globalplatform

I have implemented the SCP03t and would like to install my DER encoded network profile package on my ISD-P on my eUICC. Upon sending the 1st segment of my command with tag ´86´ I get `8600`response from eUICC which means successful. On sending the 2nd segment eUICC responds with a non-sense random (at least to me) string, then responds with error tag of `9F460102`on the 3rd command and aborts the installation.

This is an example of what I get on my 2nd command response:
`6B23AC8C1666439B66C126ECAA9B069B00800000000000000000000000000000`

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my eUICC OS doesn't accept SMS PP data Download Envelope at 140 bytes (characters); it should be 130 bytes per SMS. Also, the binary counter string used for generating the ICV should be hex in my case whereas the standard explicitly states that the counter shall be binary.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the eUICC is expecting the use of a "profile protection key" PPK?  Response "8600" suggests to me that S-ENC was accepted (but could be the WRONG key IF PPK was expected with command 86) and thus subsequent response data could be "nonsense" and eventually fail.

I realize that PPK is "optional" according to the GSMA specs, but perhaps your eUICC is expecting PPK anyway.  Regular commercial use of the PPK should be common (if not predominant).

Can you try these steps:

1. Generate a PPK-ENC, PPK-MAC and encrypt the profile package with the PPK (to generate a "bound profile package" in Figure 4 on page 30 of "GSMA SGP.22 - RSP Technical Specification" version 2.2).  PPK will need to be included with the "bound profile package".
2. As shown in Figure 4133-B on page 190 of "GSMA SGP.02" version 4.0, first send command 87 with credentials for SCP03t (S-ENC, S-MAC).
3. The response from command 87 should include the plaintext PPK-ENC, PPK-MAC from step 1.
4. Then, send command 86 with PPK-ENC, PPK-MAC, instead of the credentials for SCP03t (S-ENC, S-MAC), and continue until the profile loads.

Can you let us know if that works?  Again, this assumes the eUICC is essentially requiring the use of PPK, when it's supposed to be optional.

Finally, if my understanding of the issue is correct, your sequence before steps 1-4 above would represent "Test Sequence #05 Error: S-ENC used instead of PPK-ENC" on page 75 of SGP.23 RSP Specification Version 1.5, although the eUICC is not sending back the expected readable/usable response "R_PIR_SECU_INVALID"

Comment: Hi! :)

Sorry for my late response and thanks for all the time you took and for your comments.

I got in contact with eUICC's manufacturer and they said that profile package can be installed with session keys and there's no need to replace the session keys.

On the other hand, in the SIMAlliance standard it's stated that eUICC should be able to receive each element independently. On my tests, ISD-P recieves PE Header successfully, but when I send PE MF (using template), it returns an error with offset pertaining to the `securityAttributesReferenced '0F'H`.